# select where id = multiple values (many to many)

Tags: mysql

I am sure its a basic and old question just cant figure the right way to do it.

I have a many to many table studentindiactors

===========================

studentid | indicatorid

===========================

1         |   1

1         |   4

2         |   1

3         |   4

I want to select all studentids that have exactly 1 and 4 as their indicators therefore the result should be **1** and not 2 or 3. So i cannot use

```
select studentid from studentindicators where indicatorid in (1,4)
```

P.S: the 1 and 4 comes in as a comma separated list to the stored procedure

Comment: give a clear result here

Comment: expected result should be 1 which is the student id that has both indicators

Comment: Sorry i don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got to my answer with help from @MichaelBadgett.. The query is

```
SELECT distinct studentid FROM studentindicators WHERE  studentid IN (
  SELECT studentid FROM studentindicators WHERE indicatorid = 1) 
AND studentid IN (
  SELECT studentid FROM studentindicators WHERE indicatorid = 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple subqueries to select rows that fit in both subqueries.
In mysql you cant really test 2 seperate conditions at once. the use of AND with subqueries is likely what you want.

SELECT * FROM `studentindicators` WHERE 
`studentid` IN (SELECT `studentid` FROM `studentindicators` WHERE `indicatorid` = 1)
AND
`studentid` IN (SELECT `studentid` FROM `studentindicators` WHERE `indicatorid` = 4);

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tested it, but I'm pretty sure you can simplify the query by writing:

```
SELECT studentid FROM studentindicators WHERE indicatorid = 1 AND indicatorid = 4
```